# Chart.js Charts not loading, only one loads JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three Chart.js charts that I want to display. When I try to start the second one, it does not load, even though I put the right ID and the JS from the Chart.js docs. When I tried to change the name of the id it did not work either. I also removed the `chart-parent` `div` from the second one, but that also did not work.

It seems like only the third chart is loading. Is there a solution?

```js
/* Race/Ethnicity vs Age */ 
const data = {
    //labels: ['Younger Than 18', '18-30', '31-45', 'Older than 45', 'Unknown'],
    
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Races/Ethnicities Killed',
        data: [
          20, 30, 30, 40, 50
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        tension: 0.4,
        yAxisID: 'y'     
    }, 
    {
        label: 'Ages Killed',
        data: [
          10, 20, 30, 40, 50
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 26, 104, 1)',
        tension: 0.4,
    }]
};

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left'
          },
          x1: {
            labels: ['White (Non-Hispanic)', 'Black (Non-Hispanic)', 'Hispanic (Black Or White)', 'Asian', 'Unknown'],
          },
          x2: {
            position: 'top',
            labels: ['Younger than 18', '18-30', '31-45', 'Older than 45', 'Unknown'],
          },
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('chart'),
      config
    );

    // Instantly assign Chart.js version
    const chartVersion = document.getElementById('chartVersion');
    chartVersion.innerText = Chart.version;


/* Race */
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="box age">
    <div class="chart-parent">
      <canvas id="chartAge"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box ethnicity">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="box both">
    <div class="chart-parent">
      <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <h1>Race/Ethnicity vs. Age</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      Exercitationem placeat unde illum doloremque cumque beatae 
      veritatis nulla, culpa autem sed.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a null value arrives at this line

```
chartVersion.innerText = Chart.version;
```

You have not assigned this `<canvas id="chartAge"></canvas>` to any chart

**Corrected example**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeiryuV/o7dnczuv/18/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want to happen but you miss 1 id on it. Let me know

```js
/* Race/Ethnicity vs Age */ 
const data = {
    //labels: ['Younger Than 18', '18-30', '31-45', 'Older than 45', 'Unknown'],
    
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Races/Ethnicities Killed',
        data: [
          20, 30, 30, 40, 50
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        tension: 0.4,
        yAxisID: 'y'     
    }, 
    {
        label: 'Ages Killed',
        data: [
          10, 20, 30, 40, 50
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 26, 104, 1)',
        tension: 0.4,
    }]
};

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left'
          },
          x1: {
            labels: ['White (Non-Hispanic)', 'Black (Non-Hispanic)', 'Hispanic (Black Or White)', 'Asian', 'Unknown'],
          },
          x2: {
            position: 'top',
            labels: ['Younger than 18', '18-30', '31-45', 'Older than 45', 'Unknown'],
          },
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('chart'),
      config
    );

    // Instantly assign Chart.js version
    const chartVersion = document.getElementById('myChart');
    chartVersion.innerText = Chart.version;


/* Race */
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
 <div class="content">
            <div class="box age">
                <div class="chart-parent">
                    <canvas id="chartAge"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box ethnicity">
                    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="box both">
                <div class="chart-parent">
                    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <h1>Race/Ethnicity vs. Age</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Exercitationem placeat unde illum doloremque cumque beatae 
                    veritatis nulla, culpa autem sed.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What ID was missed? Please clarify what changes you made.

Comment: There are no ID's missing